When I run sudo apt-get upgrade, it shows errors regarding initramfs-tools
When I run sudo apt-get upgrade, I get this output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

First I used Ubuntu. 
I thought perhaps the OS was the problem, so I switched to Debian. 
All sudo apt-get-related commands fail due to this error.
My machine has enough storage (3 TB) and I use only around 1% of it.
@Stéphane Chazelas 
Here is the output from df -T / /tmp /boot:
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks     Used      Available  Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4  1920224544    377924596 1444684128  21% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4  1920224544    377924596 1444684128  21% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4  1920224544    377924596 1444684128  21% /

I have tried to use sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean,
but it always falls back to this error.
How can I fix this?

(1) Please explain what you mean by “it stays the same after a few days”. Did it work correctly at first, and then start failing a few days later, with no changes to the system in the interim? (2) The question you linked to has the same ultimate error message, but totally different details. If you simply cherry-picked the answer to that question, no wonder it didn’t change anything. If you did something more relevant to your situation than mv …/z50-raspi-firmware …, please describe it in detail.     Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

See: DebianWiki: Change Language.  Use the appropriate two-letter code when setting it.

i have updated the question. it's not because of the LC_CTYPE. even if i set the correct locale, initramfs-tools will still generate an error.

What's the output of df -T / /tmp /boot?

/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4 1920224544 377924596 1444684128  21% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4 1920224544 377924596 1444684128  21% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4 1920224544 377924596 1444684128  21% /

this the the output. from here can see that still have a lot of spaces left on my hard disk

Try sudo apt remove fuse && sudo apt install fuse3 && sudo apt autoremove  See: How to safely install fuse on Ubuntu 22.04? and Debiam Package Briwser: fuse. Fuse and Fuse 3 cannot coexist on the same system.
